# Combine two dataframes that have common rows and columns (fill in)

Tags: r, join, data-binding, bind, dplyr

I have a big dataframe that I want to fill in with results from SQL queries to many databases, so kind of "filling in data cubbyholes" so to speak. Wrinkle: I don't know how many cubbyholes will be filled in (there's a group_by year, so I might get a dataframe with one year, or many).

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to accomplish this. I'm trying to use the dplyr package..

- left_join either adds the same row twice (if I specify the `by=`), or drops the new column (if I don't specify the `by=` and thus it joins on both similar columns)[image]

  [image]
- bind_cols doesn't work
- bind_rows adds a duplicate row.

  [image]

How can I get the new data to fill in the cubbyhole itself? (btw, I'm not married to dplyr... I just don't want to iterate through every element of the new dataframe)

Code follows:

```
library(dplyr)
TargetDF <- structure(list(Ind = c(5, 6, 7), `2015 Act` = c(7870L, NA, NA
                                                            )), .Names = c("Ind", "2015 Act"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
                                                                                                         ), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

tempDF <- structure(list(Ind = 6, `2015 Act` = 49782L, `2016 Act` = 323L), .Names = c("Ind", 
                                                                                      "2015 Act", "2016 Act"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                      ), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
left_join(TargetDF,tempDF, by= "Ind")
## gives duplicate columns

left_join(TargetDF,tempDF)
## loses the new "2015 Act" data for Ind 6

bind_cols(TargetDF,tempDF)
## don't work

bind_rows(TargetDF,tempDF)
## double Ind 6 (there are other columns nor included here, which is why I can't !is.na() to eliminate duplicate Ind 6)
```

Comment: Myabe something like `full_join(TargetDF, tempDF) %>% group_by(Ind) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Thanks, solves the example, but some of the columns that I suppressed here are characters, and therefore the summarise_each results in `Error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument`

Comment: Maybe `full_join(TargetDF, tempDF) %>% group_by(Ind) %>% summarise_each(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))`

Comment: Yeah, that did it! Awesome... so the function you passed was simply 'the first non-NA value of everything'?? Wow man, you're an artist with it. Write formal answer for rep?

Comment: Actually the `[1]` part is for situations when all the values are `NA`s. This way, we are generating an `NA` because `NA[1]` is also `NA`. Otherwise `summarise_each` will return an error. I'll post an answer, but I have a feeling there could be more dplyrish way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to get the non-`NA` values out of each column grouped by `Ind`, and otherwise, leave (generate) an `NA`

```
full_join(TargetDF, tempDF) %>% 
  group_by(Ind) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1L]))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#     Ind 2015 Act 2016 Act
#   (dbl)    (int)    (int)
# 1     5     7870       NA
# 2     6    49782      323
# 3     7       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use {powerjoin}, make a left join and deal with the conflicts using `coalesce_xy` (which is really `dplyr::coalesce`) :

```
library(powerjoin)
safe_left_join(TargetDF, tempDF, by = "Ind", conflict = coalesce_xy)
# # tibble [3 x 3]
#     Ind `2015 Act` `2016 Act`
#   <dbl>      <int>      <int>
# 1     5       7870         NA
# 2     6      49782        323
# 3     7         NA         NA
```